# Create Mediawiki Edit Article Button

Tags: mediawiki

I have created a custom skin for my mediawiki that is based on vector. I already have the VIEWS tab at the top that shows the Article, Edit, History and Action. Apart from this tab, I am trying to add a new "Edit this Article" button to show at the top right hand corner of the page. I dont know how to add the edit url to this button. At the moment, I have hard coded it like this:

```
<a class="edit_article_button" href="?action=edit" title="Edit This Article">Edit Article</a>
```

The above hard coded method is no good and it doesnt work properly on all pages. It also it is not compatible when I change the Edit buttons to Edit with form buttons for Semantic Form extension. Is there like a way to add a default link to this edit button that works for that relevant mediawiki article? When I had a look at the skin, the edit button is shown as part of the renderNavigation function which is no good since it shows all the lists including History, etc..:

```
<?php $this->renderNavigation( array( 'VIEWS' ) ); ?>
```

This is where I am having trouble with and unable to find info on how to do it. Can someone help me on how I can create a separate Edit article button?

### EDIT & PROGRESS UPDATE:

Alright... Here is an update on how I was able to add it. I added the following to the renderNavigation function and it works:

```
    case 'EDIT':
            $navTemp = $this->data['content_actions']['edit'];
            if ($navTemp) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $navTemp['href']; ?>" class="custom_edit_button" title="Edit This Article"><?php echo $navTemp['text']; ?></a>
            <?php } 
            break;
```

and I am calling it using this inside the html template:

```
         <?php $this->renderNavigation( array('EDIT')); ?>
```

I also added the css for the "custom_edit_button" to style the button further.

**Next hurdle when using Semantic Form:** Although the above method works, what happens is it shows the Edit source button instead of Edit with Form button. I actually want it to show the "Edit with Form" option when there is a form present in that article instead of edit source option. I already have this in LocalSettings.php

```
 //The following settings are to edit the edit with form options and removing the default edit option.
 $sfgRenameEditTabs = true;

$wgGroupPermissions['*']['viewedittab'] = false; // Hiding the regular edit tab for all users
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['viewedittab'] = true; //Showing the regular edit tab (renamed to edit source) to sysops only.
```

Now, how can I change the above php code so it links to "Edit with form" page when there is a form present?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Skinning/Tutorial ??

Comment: Thank you Mark. Yeah I had a look at that link before. I actually used that as a reference when creating the skin. Since mine is based on Vector, for the Action tabs at the top, I used the 'content_navigation' that is also used in vector. But in that, when I enter 'VIEWS' as the array, it creates the full tab showing Page, Edit and History which I have used at the top left hand corner. But I am trying to also add an extra simple "edit button" alone inside an anchor tag at the top right side. I am not sure how to do this. I read the Content Actions section in that link but still not sure... :(

Comment: Hey Mark, I was able to get part of it working. I have updated my question above with "EDIT & PROGRESS UPDATE". After adding the above mentioned php code, the custom edit button shows but it links to edit source page. I want it to link to edit with form page when there is a form present. (I am using semantic forms). So I am stuck on that.....

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Forms/The_%22edit_with_form%22_tab has lots of information on how to make the edit tab appear as you want it.

Still, it looks like the SemanticForms extension is using the SkinTemplateNavigation hook which is called in SkinTemplate::buildContentNavigationUrls(), so make sure you aren't overriding that function.